# In safety guidelines for construction work and/or welding what is "RPE"?

Tags: safety

In North America, when you are dealing with safety guidelines, what does the abbreviation "RPE" represent in simple English words?

---

I was watching a video which explained that **RPE** is required in addition to **PPE**.

---

I already know that the abbreviation or initialism "**PPE**" is used to refer to "personal protective equipment."

---

Personal Protective equipment (**PPE**) includes:

> - gloves to protect your hands.
> - hard-toed shoes
> - safety glasses for your eyes
> - additional safety gear.

I was watching a video which explained that **RPE** is required in addition to **PPE** for some tasks. The narrator in the video never explained what **RPE** is.

If you use Google to search for **RPE** you will find that the abbreviation **RPE** is used in many different lines of work and that it is difficult to find the meaning when it comes to OSHA certified safety experts who observe welding operations to make sure things go safely.

---

## In Plain English words, what is **RPE**?

Comment: [It's in the first line of a well-formed search](https://www.google.com/search?q=osha+rpe+meaning&sca_esv=567753329&rlz=1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Respiratory protective equipment (RPE).

Stuff you need to help you keep breathing.

(For what it's worth, this isn't a common abbreviation in the US. It's much more widely used in the UK.)